# Solving heat equation on a cylinder with insulated ends and convective boundary conditions

Tags: differential-equations, regions, finite-element-method, boundary-conditions

I am trying to solve heat equation on a cylinder whose ends are thermally insulated and its circular face is exposed to convection. Therefore I have Neumann boundary condition on all faces of the cylinder. Here is my code:

```
NDSolveValue[{Laplacian[u[x, y, z], {x, y, z}] == NeumannValue[0, z == 0] + 
 NeumannValue[0, z == 1] + NeumannValue[1 - u[x, y, z],
 x^2 + y^2 == 1]}, u, {x, y, z} \[Element] Cylinder[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}}, 1]]
```

However I get the error:

```
NDSolveValue::bcnop: No places were found on the boundary where Coordinate was True, so BoundaryCondition[{Robin,{1,1},{CompiledFunction[{10,11.,5568},{_Real,_Real,_Real},{{3,0,0},{3,0,1},{3,0,2},{3,2,0}},{{{{1.}},{3,2,0}}},{0,0,3,0,1},{{1}},Function[{x,y,z},{{1.}},Listable],Evaluate],CompiledFunction[{10,11.,5568},{_Real,_Real,_Real},{{3,0,0},{3,0,1},{3,0,2},{3,2,0}},{{{{-1.}},{3,2,0}}},{0,0,3,0,1},{{1}},Function[{x,y,z},{{-1.}},Listable],Evaluate]},1},Coordinate,CompiledFunction[{10,11.,5568},{_Real,_Real,_Real},<<5>>,Evaluate],NeumannValue[1-u,x^2+y^2==1]] will effectively be ignored.
```

My question: what does `No places were found on the boundary where Coordinate was True` mean? As far I can see I have specified the faces of the cylinder correctly in the `NeumannValue` boundary conditions. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Use `NeumannValue[1 - u[x, y, z], x^2 + y^2 >= 0.9999]`.

Comment: @flinty `NeumannValue[1 - u[x, y, z], x^2 + y^2 >= 0.99]` works for me, but any number greater than 0.99 doesn't work and I get the same error as before. What's going on here?

Comment: I suspect it could be due to the discretization of the cylinder.

Comment: @flinty Thanks a lot. How can I refine the discretization?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To avoid having to tweak the boundary condition, load the finite elements package and make an actual mesh:

```
<< NDSolve`FEM`

mesh = ToElementMesh @ Cylinder[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}}, 1];

NDSolveValue[
  {
    Laplacian[u[x, y, z], {x, y, z}] ==
      + NeumannValue[0, z == 0]
      + NeumannValue[0, z == 1]
      + NeumannValue[1 - u[x, y, z], x^2 + y^2 == 1]
  },
  u,
  Element[{x, y, z}, mesh]
]
```

<s>By default the mesh will be second-order, and perhaps this is why it is able to handle the curved boundary properly.</s>
It seems that `ToElementMesh` is able to handle curved boundaries much better than the default discretisation method used by `NDSolveValue`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your solution works. Do you know how I can make the mesh finer?

Comment: @Deep Take a look at the [Element Mesh Generation tutorial](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/ElementMeshCreation.html) and the options for [`ToElementMesh`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/ref/ToElementMesh.html). Most useful to you will be the options `MaxCellMeasure` and `"MaxBoundaryCellMeasure"`.

Answer (score 6):

## Update OpenCascadeLink Free Solution

The OP indicated that they are on version 11.0 that does not include the `OpenCascadeLink`.  I do not have version 11, so I do not know if this works, but it does not depend on OpenCascade.  Note that the curved surface came out as `ElementMarker==3` in this case.

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
c1 = Cylinder[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}}, 1];
bmesh = ToBoundaryMesh[c1];
groups = bmesh["BoundaryElementMarkerUnion"];
temp = Most[Range[0, 1, 1/(Length[groups])]];
colors = ColorData["BrightBands"][#] & /@ temp
bmesh["Wireframe"["MeshElementStyle" -> FaceForm /@ colors]]
mesh = ToElementMesh[bmesh];
mesh["Wireframe"]
ufun = NDSolveValue[{Laplacian[u[x, y, z], {x, y, z}] == 
     NeumannValue[1 - u[x, y, z], ElementMarker == 3]}, 
   u, {x, y, z} ∈ mesh];
SliceContourPlot3D[
 ufun[x, y, z], "CenterPlanes", {x, y, z} ∈ 
  Cylinder[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}}, 1], PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

[image: OpenCascade Free Solution]

You can use [OpenCascadeLink](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/OpenCascadeLink/tutorial/UsingOpenCascadeLink.html) define the geometry and it will create `ElementMarkers` to the faces that you may refer to in your boundary condition specification.  This will avoid guessing at what discretization is required when the object or scale changes.

Here is an example.  Note that the $\color{Red}{Red\ Surface}$ corresponds to the curved face and is `ElementMarker==1`.

```
Needs["OpenCascadeLink`"]
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
cyl = OpenCascadeShape[c1 = Cylinder[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}}, 1]];
bmesh = OpenCascadeShapeSurfaceMeshToBoundaryMesh[cyl];
groups = bmesh["BoundaryElementMarkerUnion"];
temp = Most[Range[0, 1, 1/(Length[groups])]];
colors = ColorData["BrightBands"][#] & /@ temp
bmesh["Wireframe"["MeshElementStyle" -> FaceForm /@ colors]]
mesh = ToElementMesh[bmesh];
mesh["Wireframe"]
ufun = NDSolveValue[{Laplacian[u[x, y, z], {x, y, z}] == 
     NeumannValue[1 - u[x, y, z], ElementMarker == 1]}, 
   u, {x, y, z} ∈ mesh];
SliceContourPlot3D[
 ufun[x, y, z], "CenterPlanes", {x, y, z} ∈ 
  Cylinder[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}}, 1], PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

[image: Workflow]

Comment: Unfortunately I am unable to load `OpenCascadeLink`. I am using Mathematica 11.0.

Comment: @Deep Look at the update and see if it works.  I do not have v11, so I cannot test.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

I think it has to do with discretizing the region. Consider:

```
NDSolveValue[{Laplacian[u[x, y, z], {x, y, z}] == 
   NeumannValue[0, z == 0] + NeumannValue[0, z == 1] + 
    NeumannValue[1 - u[x, y, z], 0.999 <= x^2 + y^2 <= 1.001]}
 , u, {x, y, z} \[Element] Cylinder[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}}, 1]]
```

This produces your error. However, if we soften up the condition x^2+y^2==1 a bit, then it works:

```
NDSolveValue[{Laplacian[u[x, y, z], {x, y, z}] == 
   NeumannValue[0, z == 0] + NeumannValue[0, z == 1] + 
    NeumannValue[1 - u[x, y, z], 0.99 <= x^2 + y^2 <= 1.01]}
 , u, {x, y, z} \[Element] Cylinder[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}}, 1]]
(*InterpolatingFunction[{{-1., 1.}, {-1., 1.}, {0., 1.}}, <>]*)
```